# How to set Current date to MySQL date column from Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a   DATE  datatype mysql column in a table. I want to set the value of that column from my java code in the format  YYYY-MM-DD

I used following code to test these formats..

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
String d = c.YEAR+ "-"+c.MONTH+"-"+c.DATE;
```

But I get some wierd output if i print out that value in console. Please help. How else can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is:

```
String d = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "-" + c.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

If I remember correctly you also have to add +1 to the month as it returns offset (counted from 0) instead of just month value (which is stupid for me, but I didn't do the design).

Also, you might like to check [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and its capabilities to format a date in nice way.

Answer (score 4):

In JDBC you can use the `setDate()` method to set DATE value in the prepared statement, see [the API of PreparedStatement](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). This converts the value to the DATE type in the database.

```
PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("some query with a DATE field");
Date d = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
// just an example (its the java.sql.Date class, not java.util.Date)
prep.setDate(index, d);
// ...
```

To get this *java.sql.Date* object back with the value of the DATE field use the `getDate()` method of the [ResultSet class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

```
ResultSet res = con.executeQuery("some query with a DATE field");
Date d = res.getDate(index);
```

You can work with the `d` object like a `java.util.Date` object (like using in a `Calendar` object) as it extends from it.